# How to get distinct result from left join SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, server

My `Data` is returning result with multiple result with cd.Id2, I would like cd.Id2 to be distinct. If Data result has five cd.Id2 there are the same I would like to only get the first result of every duplicated cd.Id2.

```
> SELECT Id
>        ,IsIncluded
>        ,LineId
>        ,LineType
>        ,LineNumber
>        ,LineDescription
>          ,SUM(table2.StartBalance) AS StartBalance
>          ,SUM(table1.MoneyIn) AS MoneyIn
>          ,SUM(t1.MoneyOut) AS MoneyOut
> FROM Data AS table1
> LEFT JOIN StartBalanceData table2  ON table1.Id2 = table2.Id
```

Comments:

> Data multiple of same ID (join on first)

> StartBalanceData to map with ID

```
> GROUP BY Id, IsIncluded, LineId, LineType, LineNumber, LineDescription
```

I tried using LIMIT 1. but it is not supported.

**IMAGE OF EXPECTED RESULT**

https://pasteboard.co/inNzvmtEI2ux.png

Comment: Your query is hard to read because aliases are only used where it matters but not where it counts. In theory as long as all data from alias od is excluded in the output and grouping this query shall return the data you want. If not please provide a data sample and table definitions to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results. The real question will be, when these duplicates occur and you want "first result"... how would you define the order to determine "first result".

Answer (score 0):

You could do an OUTER APPLY instead which gets one row only:

```sql
SELECT Id
        ,IsIncluded
        ,LineId
        ,LineType
        ,LineNumber
        ,LineDescription
          ,SUM(x.StartBalance) AS StartBalance
          ,SUM(table1.MoneyIn) AS MoneyIn
          ,SUM(t1.MoneyOut) AS MoneyOut
 FROM Data AS table1
 OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 1 table2.StartBalance
     FROM StartBalanceData table2 
     WHERE table1.Id2 = table2.Id
     ORDER BY <SOMETHING???>
    ) x
```

Since you were helpful enough to avoid cluttering your question with details like testdata or about which balance data you want to preferably fetch, it's hard to write a complete query, but perhaps this might get you started